# Using SUMPRODUCT for multiple conditions including WEEKDAY and cell containing specific text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, weekday, sumproduct

I'm trying to get a count-output for cells in a particular sheet

So I have a table of content in sheet A "Trade Report"
[> Trade Report Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DdE2.png)

In simple terms, I want to count the number of trades made on a Monday for a specific Pair, in this case "NZD/USD" that had a positive outcome, so >0 in column H

So far I can't even get a value to return for Trades made on the NZD/USD Pair made on a Monday, the closest I've come thus far is counting how many trades were made on a Monday using this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY('Trade Report'!B3:INDEX('Trade Report'!B:B,MATCH(1E+99,'Trade Report'!B:B)))=2))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm practically pulling my hair out at this point :')

Comment: @OleV.V. that's just an Excel formula and it was tagged as such.

Comment: Apologies, I'm quite new to using this forum and am a little hopeless >__<